# What happens to SHiFT rewards once Live Gold runs out?

Tags: borderlands-2

I play Borderlands 2 on an Xbox 360.  In order to redeem SHiFT rewards on the Xbox version of the game, you have to have Xbox LIVE Gold.  I have Gold, but my wife does not, so up to this point she's been golden key code-less.

However, this weekend is free Gold level benefits for everyone, which means that her normally Silver account is now eligible to redeem codes.  I signed her up for a SHiFT account and redeemed a good 15 keys worth of codes.

However, her Gold will run out at the end of the weekend, and all Gold subscriptions are technically time limited - mine will run out eventually, even.

What happens to our SHiFT rewards when time runs out?  Do we get to keep any unlocked golden keys?

Comment: I know on the PC version, you redeem the key online, but then it is stored in your personal profile.  I would expect it works the same way on XBox and you should have them after gold expires.

Comment: I was under the impression that GearBox SHiFT is all done on GearBox's servers, so there shouldn't be any issue with live expiring. Needing gold to access it through Xbox Live is just an MS requirement, I doubt MS exposes subscriber info to GearBox when a subscription expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you redeem SHiFT rewards while you have Gold status, and your Gold status expires, you can still use the existing rewards you redeemed during your Gold membership.

You get to keep any unlocked items, and your key count is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only place on the net addressing this question, I'm frustrated that there is one "yes" and one "no" as to whether you get to use your keys after your account expires. So I decided to test it out on my own.

Last night, on the eve of my account expiring, I used all keys but one. Today, after confirming my Xbox live Gold account had expired, I went to Sanctuary and used my last Golden Key. No problems, I got the standard 2 purple items.

**Yes, you get to keep and use your Golden Keys after your Xbox Gold account has expired.**

Answer (score -1):

you CANNOT use keys once your gold subscription expires, just found this out yesterday, but you keep the guns you unlocked with the keys.  Sucks that you're required to pay xbox fee's to use the chest!